# Project base directory PHP

Tags: php, path, directory, project

I'm working on a project organized this way:

```
public_html/
   index.php
   file1.php
   file2.php
   ...
   css/
      basic.css
   panel/
      file3.php
      ...
resources/
   classes/
      class1.php
      class2.php
      ...
   core/
      init.php
   includes/
      templates/
         header.php
         footer.php
```

Here is a part of what I have got in my `init.php` file:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once '../resources/classes/' . $class . '.php';
}
);
```

In every php file, I simply require `init.php`:

```
<?php

require_once '../resources/core/init.php';
```

I get the result with files inside `public_html` folder, but when I do this with files inside `panel` subfolder, PHP can't find my classes (same thing for templates).
I would like to know, what is the best way to deal with this problem?

P.S I'm working on `localhost/`

Also inside header.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic.css" type="text/css" />
        <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
    </head>
```

When calling it from `public_html` folder, everything works just fine, when calling from `panel` subfolder, no CSS...

Comment: Try using absolute path. because if you call from `panel` the path should be `../../resources/core/init.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `__DIR__`. The `__DIR__` constant evaluates to the directory which contains the file where it is used (it does not include the trailing slash).

```
<?php

// resources/bootstrap.php

# /some/project/dir/resources
echo __DIR__;
```

Use `dirname(__DIR__)` to go one level up.

Also, notice `__DIR__` is available in PHP ≥5.3.0, in older versions you must use `dirname(__FILE__)`.